# jmeter v5.1.1 - cannot generate html report

Tags: jmeter, test-report

I have a result file of Concurrency Thread Group test of 500 users.
The file has aproximetly 58K rows and 16Mb

1) I tried generating a report through "Tool > Generate html report" but get time-out exception, I have increased the timer to 480000 but the result was the same.

2) I tried generate report through cmd -> it was running for a few hours and again no result, no report, all logs files have no exceptions.

Is there limitation of a report's rows?
please help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a jtl file with result stats? Use this command then:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/jtl/file -o /where/you/want/to/store/dashboard
```

In case you want to generate the report dashboard post run, use this command instead:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan -l /path/to/result.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard/folder
```

You may also want to visit your user.properties file and a JMeter restart may be needed as well, Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Rohan, Yes I do have the result of my test in csv and jtl format, and as I've wrote, I've tried generating the HTML report by 2 ways: Jmeter Tools (in v5.1.1) and cmd.

Comment: Did you try the aforementioned ways I suggested? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did. I got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while generating the HTML report while my HEAP set is -Xms1024m -Xmx10240m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m

Comment: HtmlReportGenerator: The HTML report generation failed and returned: An error occurred: Java heap space